# Vee-validate: Getting "TypeError: checks is null" error when using v-validate directive

Tags: javascript, validation, vuejs2, vee-validate

I am using vee-validate in my VueJs 2 project.
The problem is that, whenever I am using the v-validate directive in the input field, I am getting below error in my console window:-

```
[Vue warn]: Error in directive validate bind hook: "TypeError: checks is null"
```

What could be the reason for this error?
I've already imported the vee-validate module in my app.js file and I am using the directive in my form component.

Comment: Post some context, please...

Comment: I am having the same issue using the basic example posted on the VeeValidate site.

Comment: please add more context or link to which example on the VeeValidate site or create a jsfiddle